# HHVM doesn't start and no error message

Tags: centos, centos6, hhvm

I've installed HHVM 3.2 on Centos 6.5. And also installed mod_fastcgi. But when I try to start hhvm nothing happens. I don't see any error message. I have to press ctrl + c to interrupt.

Where can I check for any errors? As for mod_fastcgimod_fastcgi, do I need to configure anything for hhvm?

Thanks in advance